# How to use libraries across an r notebook?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

I wish to use libraries across multiple .Rmd files in an r notebook without having to reload the library each time.

An example: I have loaded the library kableExtra in the index.Rmd file but when I call it in another .Rmd file such as ExSum.Rmd I would get this error:

Error in Kable....: could not find funciton "kable" Calls:...

If I load the kableExtra library again this problem goes away. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

R Markdown files are intended to be standalone, so you shouldn't do this.  There are two workarounds that come close:

1. If you process your .Rmd files within the R console by running code like `rmarkdown::render("file.Rmd")` then any packages attached in the session will be available to the code in the .Rmd file.
2. You can put all the setup code (e.g. `library(kableExtra)`) into a file (called `setup.R`, for example), and source it into each document in the first code chunk using `source('setup.R')`.  Every file will run the same setup, but you only need to type it once.

The second is the better approach.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the second options seems best. I'm writing a report with some repetitive code in multiple sections in r notebooks. So, I don't want to repeat the same code every time.